# Mysql time diff in group by

Tags: mysql

I have a `times` table. I would like to create a view, that would give me primary key and all time diffs for all sensors.

Sensors are as fallow:

```
 0.   start
 1-3. on track timers
 4.   end
```

Example will show the best:

```
Times table:
----------------------------------------------------------
| TimeID | RaceID | RacerID | Round | Sensor |    Time    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |    1   |    1    |   1   |    0   |   100540   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   2    |    1   |    2    |   1   |    0   |   154297   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   3    |    1   |    1    |   1   |    1   |   170134   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   4    |    1   |    2    |   1   |    1   |   185915   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   5    |    1   |    1    |   1   |    2   |   200137   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   6    |    1   |    2    |   1   |    2   |   235103   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   7    |    1   |    1    |   1   |    4   |   380123   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   8    |    1   |    2    |   1   |    4   |   421127   |
-----------------------------------------------------------

Desired view
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| TimeID | RaceID | RacerID | Round | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 |   Total |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |    1   |    1    |   1   | 69594 | 99597 |  null |  279583 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |    1   |    2    |   1   | 31618 | 80806 |  null |  266830 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10c5f/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, just use a series of `left join`s:

```
SELECT t0.timeID , t0.raceID, t0.racerID, t1.time - t0.time as 'Time 1',
t2.time - t1.time as 'Time 2', t3.time - t3.time as 'Time 3', t4.time - t0.time as 'Total'
FROM time t0 left join
time t1 on t0.racerID = t1.racerID and t1.sensor = 1 left join
time t2 on t0.racerID = t2.racerID and t2.sensor = 2 left join
time t3 on t0.racerID = t3.racerID and t3.sensor = 3 left join
time t4 on t0.racerID = t4.racerID and t4.sensor = 4 
where t0.sensor = 0
```

Comment: This solution definitly works, but is it effective? I would have to check for raceID, racerID, and round (thought I can index them)

Comment: There's no problem with indexing, if you index `racerID` and `sensor` fields the DB should be able to use them. Why do you think its not efficient?

Comment: I suppose yes... And about efficiency, it is probably efficient enough, since it will use the one table only.

Answer (score 0):

You can not dynamically add columns, so either you need to specify what Time1 makes Time1 by expressing that in an aggregate function expression in your SELECT clause and so forth for all the values you want, which probably can't be done since you're expressing a relation to other values. MIN or MAX could come close, but "the second least" or "second most" values can not be expressed, since it implies a relation to other values separately aggregated.

You could consider GROUP_CONCAT, which probably comes closest to what you want.